# Why not return const-reference in operator= instead of a reference?

Tags: c++

While in assignment operator overloading why we return a reference to the object and why it can't return a const-reference? For example, in this case:

```
MyClass& MyClass::operator=(const MyClass &rhs) {
    ...  // Do the assignment

    return *this;
  }
```

Why we can't return a constant reference like:

```
const MyClass& MyClass::operator=(const MyClass &rhs) {
    ...  // Do the assignment operation!

    return *this;  // Return a reference to myself.
  }
```

Comment: You can, but why would you? `*this` is non-const here, why add constness?

Comment: Sure you can, but what benefit would it serve? If you do, you disallow expressions like `(a = b).NonConstMember();`.

Comment: The return type can be `MyClass const&`.  It could even be `void`.  Either of which may be surprising to someone that expects (and relies upon) more typical behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can, but the users of `MyClass` may be surprised.

Usually, references can be taken to assignments (and less often, assignments can be assigned again). This is slightly confusing to word correctly, so here's what it looks like:

```
int a = 4;
int &r = a = 5;
(a = 6) = 7;
```

This also disallows calling member functions that modify the arguments of the function, for example:

```
#include <iostream>

struct C
{
    int value;
    const C &operator=(int v){value = v; return *this;}
};

void assign_value(C &ref)
{
    ref %= 4;
}

int main(void)
{
    C test;
    assign_value(test = 5);
    std::cout << c.value << '\n';
}
```

Comment: Honestly, I prefer to disallow such kind of code in my app: (test=5).multiply_by(4).

Comment: @Gupta This is just a contrived example. I'm sure there's some much better way to show that a `const` return value on `operator=` is bad, but I can't think of one right now.

Comment: Yeah, I am still not convinced by this example.

Comment: `foo(test = 5);` is probably a more "frequent" example. chained initialization `(test = myObject).SetSpeed(42).SetAccelleration(12);` (but I don't think they use `operator=` in that case).

Comment: Although I would say example wasn't that great but I am finally able to understand